# How to read a js page before another

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

```js
function animatePlayer() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

    let position = Math.floor(gameFrame/staggerFrame) % spriteAnimation[playerState].loc.length
    let frameX = spriteWidth * position
    let frameY = spriteAnimation[playerState].loc[position].y

    ctx.drawImage(playerImage, frameX, frameY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, playerPositionX, playerPositionY, 150, 150)
    gameFrame++
    //playerImage.style.zIndex = "1"
    requestAnimationFrame(animatePlayer)
}
animatePlayer()
```

I have three Js pages for my canvas project, I wanted to separate each element because it was getting too messy. My "bg.js" is my background so I want it to be at the back of the canvas while my "enemies.js" are my enemies so I want them to appear in front of the page and not hidden behind my background. Please let me know if I need to include more code.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="bg.js" defer></script>
    <script src="enemies.js" defer></script>
    <title>Game</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
function animateBG(){
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    allLayers.forEach(object =>  {
        object.update(),
        object.draw()
    })

    requestAnimationFrame(animateBG)
}
animateBG()
```

Comment: so.. what is your question?

Comment: how can I throw my "bg,js" in the back in order for my enemies to appear?

Comment: how about use two canvas ?

Comment: I get a feeling you should be using a gaming engine... here is a collection of Open Source ones: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines

Answer (score 0):

Generally there's no problem with 'outsourcing' your code-base to multiple JavaScript source files. Problems arise if there are - as in your case are two - conflicting actions.

Both `animateBG` and `animatePlayer` are drawing to a shared HTML `<canvas>` element - e.g. clearing it and drawing something afterwards and again both also have it's own `requestAnimationFrame()`. Those two actions though are not synchronized to each other. So it might and it does happen that the background overwrites the player and vice versa.

Get rid of the individual `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)` and `requestAnimationFrame()` calls in those functions and just set-up a single function which updates your game's visual. This could be stored in an additional .js file.

Something like:

## bg.js

```
function animateBG(){
    allLayers.forEach(object =>  {
        object.update(),
        object.draw()
    });
}
```

## enemies.js

```
function animatePlayer() {
    let position = Math.floor(gameFrame/staggerFrame) % spriteAnimation[playerState].loc.length
    let frameX = spriteWidth * position
    let frameY = spriteAnimation[playerState].loc[position].y

    ctx.drawImage(playerImage, frameX, frameY, spriteWidth, spriteHeight, playerPositionX, playerPositionY, 150, 150)
    gameFrame++
}
```

## newFile.js

```
function update()
{
     ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
     animateBG();
     animatePlayer();
}
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

This new `update()` function first clears the canvas, then draws the background and finally draws the player.